# Regex - replace character with alternating characters

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I have very little understanding of Regex and I'm afraid the myriad of tutorials out there aren't doing much to improve my situation.
What I'd like is to take a string and replace a specific delimiter with alternating characters, thus create a name/value pair.
This is for SEO url rewriting purposes - using IIS Rewrite.

So for instance if I have the following URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/mypage_foo_bar_megafoo_freebar_nofoo_closedbar.htm
```

I need to use regex to rewrite this to:

```
http://mydomain.com/mypage.cfm?foo=bar&megafoo=freebar&nofoo=closedbar
```

I've been attempting this for a while and have gotten nowhere - can anyone help me out?

Thanks

EDIT: I realise this is not a great example of a good URL structure - it's a legacy system and I'm not allowed to offer alternatives... alas.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only replacing underscores, you can probably do this without regex. By using the `replaceFirst()` method in whichever language your using. With regex you would only be detecting underscores and replacing them, same as this. Something like;

```
myURL = myURL.replaceFirst("_",".cfm?");
while(myURL.contains("_"))
{
    myURL = myURL.replaceFirst("_","=");
    myURL = myURL.replaceFirst("_","&");
}
```

If you need a more complicated one to prevent detection of underscores in other parts of the URL if you outline what the possible combinations for that are I can probably help you find a suitable pattern to separate the domain from the parameters prior to replacement.

According to the download page, you are doing this in .net?
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

---

Ok I've had a read of this page;
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module
You will need a match string such as;

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).htm
```

And a replace string such as

```
{R:1}.cfm?{R:2}={R:3}
```

You will then need to repeat this for increasing number of variable pairs until you see fit e.g.
Match string;

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).htm
```

Replace string;

```
{R:1}.cfm?{R:2}={R:3}&{R:2}={R:3}
```

The system appears designed for known get requests, rather than any random page and number of get requests. There isn't any mention of how to apply repeating patterns in that guide.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an option - I'd happily do this in ColdFusion on a couple of lines, but for URL Rewriting I need to do the entire thing in Regex on a single line. I can't, as far as I'm aware, do a replace and then refer to the result in a second replace.

Comment: I appreciate your time here - this will work, but doesn't resolve my problem. I won't know how many variables to expect on any given page, and in some cases there will be very many... I've read there's a limit of nine backreferences in any one redirect. I could, feasibly, chain redirects... but I think at this point my best option is to rewrite to an intermediary .cfm script which will read the query string and redirect accordingly.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the functionality I need to replicate here is available in a module for IIS - LinkFreeze by Helicon. Their software allows you to replace the ?, =, and & characters with one of your choice and handles the redirect... I can't get it working with a .NET 4.0 application pool, which I need because (to complicate matters further) I have colons in the URLs as well (legacy... legacy...) and .NET 2.0 can't handle it. Point being though, there must be a way to reference and replace the delimiters rather than the parameters. Unless perhaps they hit http.sys directly?